# android/ios web based application to lock pages on landscape but others on portrait

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

i have i activity that loads a web based app..in my web page i have a couple of pages that i want to load in the main activity of my android app.my question is if it possible to lock some pages of my web based app to landscape with out affecting the other pages?i know that to lock the main activity to landscape all other pages will be lock to landscape and i don't want it to happened i just want selected pages to lock on landscape and other on portrait. is there a way in android to do this trick? i'm using jquery in my web based app.

Comment: Web Application in Browser or App with Web View using jQuery Mobile ?

Comment: its android app with web view just 1 activity to load a web based application with atleast 5 pages i want some of it to load on landscape because of width and others on portrait because of height problems.